# Prove an equivalence of asymptotic formulas

Tags: asymptotics

I have the following:

$$\Omega\left(\frac{\log N}{\log\log N}\right)\leq n.$$

The claim is that this implies
$$N\leq n^{O(n)}.$$

I have made no progress on proving that this is true. Does anybody have an idea of where to start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to prove by contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log N \ll n \log\log N \tag{1}$$
$$ N \leq \exp(C n \log\log N) = (\log N)^{Cn}\ll(n\log\log N)^{Cn} \tag{2}$$
$$ \log\log N \ll \log(n)+\log\log\log N \tag{3}$$
If we keep using $\log N\ll n\log\log N$ in the RHS of $(3)$ we end up with
$$ \log\log N \ll \log(n)+\log\log(n)+\log\log\log(n)+\ldots \ll \log^2(n) \tag{4}$$
which plugged into $(2)$ gives
$$ N \ll (n \log^2(n) )^{Cn} \ll n^{(C+\varepsilon)n}.\tag{5} $$

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you!